# What DB permissions are available for queries through data.SE?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is there any documentation on what is/isn't permitted on data.SE?

Specifically can I create:

- views
- temp-tables
- procedures
- functions

Do I have my own schema to play with?

Comment: For those looking for schema documentation please refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/166536

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty much permitted to do anything that the system allows you to execute*. With that in mind, the database user used to execute user queries has the following [set of permissions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75384) for any given site's database:

- CONNECT
- SHOWPLAN
- SELECT

Excluding the operations from your list that require additional permissions leaves you with the ability to create temporary tables, since any user can do that.

> Do I have my own schema to play with?

No, you're running queries against the same schema in use by all other users of the system.

<sup>* Though running intentionally abusive queries (i.e. ones that make the server sad-face) is grounds for being banned, of course</sup>

Comment: Thanks Tim :)  I will definitely avoid any server sad-face action.